# How to access list from a child within a child?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a program where I let the user add items to a list view. These items are then stored in a list that makes it really easy for me to load the list view on startup using a StreamReader. Now, here's my problem. The user can select an item in the list view and then click a button to show a window that basically shows more information about the item that the user has selected. In order to change, lets say, the name, I want to open yet ANOTHER window where the user can enter the new name which is then changed and saved into the list when pressing a button.

I can easily access the list from the first child by sending an instance of Form1 to Form2 using a constructor. But how do I go about accessing Form1 from Form3 when Form3 is opened from Form2?

I use the following code to access Form1 in Form2:

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{  
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
    form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    form2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Form2:

```
private Form1 _Form1;

public Form2(Form1 _Form1)
{
    this._Form1 = _Form1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"how do I go about accessing `Form1` from `Form3` when `Form3` is opened from `Form2`"*

Well, since `Form2` has access to the instance of `Form1`, if `Form3` needs it then `Form2` can give it.

One way is to pass it through the constructor, as you did previously:

```
public class Form2
{
    private Form1 _Form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        this._Form1 = form1;
    }

    // Imaginary method that needs to pass Form1 to Form3
    public string GetName()
    {
        // Pass our reference to Form1 to the constructor of Form3
        Form3 form3 = new Form3(this._Form1);
        form3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        form3.ShowDialog(this);

        return form3.txtName.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! sending _Form1 into Form3 using this._Form1 fixed it. You're a life saver!!!